# Permission denied on file under /tmp

Tags: bash, output

I have a bash script that reads filenames, takes a selection of data, build a table, and then adds the header. Unfortunately, at the point to add the header and give the output file, I have the following error message:

```
./big_table_rcp.sh: line 153: /tmp/out: Permission denied
```

It is linked with the following line:

```
| cat - out_${scenario}.txt > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out ${gauge}_${scenario}.txt
```

Does anyone know how to give access to the output file?

Comment: You should probably use a unique filename. The problem is that `/tmp/out` was already used by someone else, and you can't overwrite their file.

Comment: does /tmp/out already exist? can you write to it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may be getting permission errors because you don't have permissions to access `/tmp/out` or the `/tmp` directory.

Before the offending line, include somehting like `ls -l /tmp | grep out` to see what permissions the `/tmp/out` file has.

In addition, instead of using `/tmp/out`, use `mktemp`.

```
tmpfile=`mktemp`
your code here | cat - out_${scenario}.txt > "$tmpfile" && mv "$tmpfile" ${gauge}_${scenario}.txt
```

From `man mktemp`:

> Create  a temporary file or directory, safely, and print its name.

Answer (score 5):

Do not use `/tmp/out`, but rather `/tmp/out.$$` this will not conflict in case of concurrent running, or leftover process, better still, use `/tmp/out.${LOGNAME}.$$` which will allow for a user level cleanup.